# Can Nxingx do Reverse Proxy updates without downtime

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have nginx that I am using to receive traffic for multiple domains on port 80 each with upstream to different application servers on application specific ports

e.g

abc.com:80 --> :3345
xyz.com:80 --> :3346

Is it possible to 
1. add/delete domains (abc/xyz) without downtime
2. change application level port mapping (3345,3346) without downtime

If nginx can't do it, is there any other service that can do it without restarting the service and incurring downtime ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Yes.

Typically, you'd overwrite the existing config file(s) in place while nginx is running, test it using `nginx -t` and once everything is fine, reload nginx using `nginx -s reload`. This will cause nginx to spawn new worker processes which use your new config while old worker processes are being shut down gracefully.. Graceful means closing listen sockets while still serving currently active connections. Every new request/connection will use the new config.

Note that in case nginx is not able to parse the new config file(s), the old config will stay in place.